# Alter from workgroup to domain to workgroup again

Tags: windows-domain, workgroup

I have a few user accounts on my computer (windows 7) and currently have it in a workgroup. When I change it into domain and then change back to workgroup, will the former mentioned user accounts be deleted or be unmodified?

Answer (score 1):

They shouldn't be.
Except if your domain has a domain controler that applies specific GPOs.
They could be ways to alter local accounts using GPOs.
If there's nothing like that, then your accounts are safe.